# Find the average lowest item in a collection grouped by date in SQL

Tags: sql

My SQL isn't the best - I can get this working in C# but it seems more efficient to get it in my data layer - I've got a table `Prices`:

| ID | Price | DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |

Each row is exactly 1 hour from the next, so I have a snapshot of a price every hour.

I'm trying to work out which hour in a day over the entire dataset has the lowest price (on average).

So ideally I'm after a list of each hour in the day ranked by how cheap on average that hour is over the entire dataset - so a maximum of 24 rows (one for each hour in the day).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks :D

Comment: Please, read this: [Ask]

Answer (score 2):

Which database are you on?
Different DBs have different ways to extract date from a timestamp column.
Postgres has `date(timestamp)`, In Oracle, you can use `trunc(timestamp)`. Or most DBs have `to_char/to_date`. So you can try that.

Once you have extracted the date, you can try something like this -

```
select ID,
Price,
DateTime,
trunc(DateTime) as day,
rank() over (partition by trunc(DateTime) order by Price asc) as least_for_day
from Prices
```

Now you can use the "least_for_day" ranked column and select by day.
Again, depending on the DB, you can either directly `qualify` on the ranked column in the same SQL or use the above as a sub-query and filter for the rank.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - much appreciated.  I'm on Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - would that work for this? Seems to kind of work, something to get going with anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like below

```
select 
hour,
avg(daily_rank) avg_rank
from
(
select *, hour= format((datetime as datetime),'HH'), daily_rank= dense_rank() over (partition by cast(datetime as date) order by price asc)
) t
group by hour
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - would this work in Microsoft SQL Server 2017?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much to @Many Manjunath and @DhruvJoshi. Final solution below;

```
WITH prices AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [Price],
        [DateTime],
        CAST([DateTime] AS TIME) 'Time',
        CAST([DateTime] as date) 'Date',
        rank() over (partition by cast([DateTime] as date) order by [Price] asc) as least_for_day
    FROM [dbo].[Prices]
)

SELECT [Time], count(*) 'Qty Cheapest' FROM prices
WHERE least_for_day = 1
GROUP BY [Time]
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

That returns 24 rows:

[image]